# How to map AltGr to Ctrl+Alt

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap, keys, xkb

I would like to map the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key on my keyboard to produce <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>. I am aware of `xkb` and `xmodmap`. As far as I could tell, however, using those you can only map from key combinations onto single keys, not the other way round.

Comment: You can also access the single-key alternatives for AltGr using the GUI  --  to to settings-->Keyboard-->Shortcuts-->Typing-->Alternative Characters Key  -- this will give you a drop down with several options. None of them are ctrl+alt, but I figure that it might be useful to others reading this thread.

Comment: btw: how in the high heavens is this a duplicate of the linked question? i swaer to god, sometimes i feel like they don'T even read the question.

Answer (score 1):

After trying and failing to get it to work with a combination of xbindkeys and xvkbd/xte (I could never get certain characters `{`, `[`, `]`, `}`, `\`, etc. to behave properly, perhaps because I use a Scandinavian keyboard layout), I finally found a simple and practical solution: **Autokey**. Here are the exact instructions to get it working:

1. Install Autokey through Ubuntu Software (I used the GTK-version, not KDE) or by: `sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk`.
2. Configure one script per key, e.g. for `{` use this code: `keyboard.send_keys("<alt_gr>+7")` and set the hotkey to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> (first set hotkey to 7 then add Ctrl and Alt as modifiers). This at least worked for the most important code-writing keys: `{ [ ] } \`.
3. Add autokey to Startup Applications (search for “start” to find it) and then add a program with “autokey” as the command.

This solution will work for anything running in the current X-session (I think) but will not work if you start a new terminal session using Ctrl+Alt+[F2-F6].